# Como eu monto um array tipo List ou Ienumerable no Controller e passo pra uso da View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Boa Noite! Fiz uma requisição ao meu webapi para buscar dados de modo a usá=lo em uma `DropDownlist @Html.DropDownList("Id","Descricao")`. Em Meu controller, consigo puxar resultados do WebApi em coleção, tratei o Json e Coloquei na minha classe produto, que só possui Id e Descricao `List<Produto>`

Como faço para, antes de retornar a view onde vou usar essa lista, criar um Objeto em lista para se vincular ao meu modelo da view e poder usar como dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo de como fazer:

```
public class Pedido {   
     public int ProdutoId {get;set;}    
     public List<Produto> Produtos {get;set;} 
}
```

no seu controller:

```
public ActionResult ExemploController(){
        var pedido = new Pedido();
        pedido.Produtos.Add(new Produto(){....});
        pedido.Produtos.Add(new Produto(){....});
        pedido.Produtos.Add(new Produto(){....});
}
```

Na sua view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProdutoId, new SelectList(Model.Produtos, "Id", "Descrição"), "Selecione")
```

ou

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProdutoId", 
                    new SelectList(Model.Produtos, "Id", "Descrição"),
                    "Selecione")
```

Comment: Só complementando, você tem que falar qual a tipagem da sua View para fazer o bind, no caso coloque algo como: @model List<Produto>

Comment: no meu caso ele teria que usar "@model Pedido" e não "@model List<Produtos>". Caso ele só precise da lista, aí eu precisaria mudar o meu exemplo